# How to hide a secret in a Flutter flavor?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, conditional-compilation, android-productflavors

I want my app to have two flavors: users' version and developers' version. Apparently, it is to be done with Flutter flavors.

I want developers' version to contain a "secret developers' key". How to ensure that users' version package does not contain secret developers' key (so, to make it impossible for a hacker to download it from Google Play and extract secret developers' key).

I use Android. In the future I also want to compile for iOS, and to be sure it won't contain the secret developers' key.

Comment: IMO you're approaching this wrong. The dev version should never be deployed, you should use 2 diferent package names/bunlde ids. One for dev and one for prod. In this way you don't have to add any secrets to production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. Consider everything in the app as public and open. You can make it harder to extract the "secret developers key", but it is not impossible.